# How to check that app has push notification on PhoneGap Build?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-build

I'm implementing push notification functionality on PGB. I use cordova 2.9.0

I would like change the main page when app has started (no coldstart, no foreground) and it has a push notification. So i need code like this:

```
if [app has push notification] { 
   $.mobile.changePage("X_Page", { transition: "pop", changeHash: false}); 
   ... 
   navigator.notification.alert([text]); 
}
```

Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to have to use local storage to store the value.

For example, on first install, set the value to true and set the app to receive notifications. If a user changes this in your app's settings page, set the value to false in local storage. Then, whenever you want to check that value, just pull it from local storage.

Comment: thank for advice but you got me wrong. Let's see the situation:
I have an app that can receive push notifications with no problem. However, if push notification comes in, then goes to the notification center, and I just open the app normally, the app doesn't know about that notification at all. Is there some "eventlistener" that I can listen to, for whenever push notification comes in?